# getting started with flot in rails4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, flot

I'd like some pointers getting a **flot** "hello world" equivalent running in my **rails4** app.  I've found lots of examples of creating lovely graphs, but I'm stuck at the basics, like,

- Once I've downloaded and unzipped flot-0.8.2.zip file, where do I put all those .js files?
- Do I *need* all those .js files?
- What do I add to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file?
- ...etc.

I'd prefer NOT to use a gem -- at least not yet -- because I want to learn what's going on under the hood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question after looking at some Heroku examples:

#### setup:

- go to http://www.flotcharts.org/
- download http://www.flotcharts.org/downloads/flot-0.8.2.zip (or whatever's newest) to the directory of your choice
- unzip it
- copy jquery.flot.js to the /app/assets/javascripts directory
- edit /app/assets/javascripts/application.js to include the jquery.flot.js, as in:

  ```
  //= require jquery
  //= require jquery_ujs
  //= require jquery.flot.js
  //= require turbolinks
  //= require_tree .
  ```

#### make a graph:

In any view file, (e.g. /app/views/myclass/index.html.erb), add the following:

```
<!-- create a placeholder for the flot graph -->
<div id="flot-placeholder" style="width:300px; height: 200px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var d1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5) {
        d1.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
    }
    var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];
    // A null signifies separate line segments
    var d3 = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]];
    $.plot("#flot-placeholder", [ d1, d2, d3 ]);
});
</script>
```

#### test it:

Render the page.  You should see something similar to http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/basic-usage/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest using [chartkicks](https://rubygems.org/gems/chartkick), a rubygem?

Installation:

1. add the gem to your gemfile
2. In application.js, add:

   //= require Chart.bundle
   //= require chartkick
3. Check out the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chartkick/2.0.0) to figure out how to manipulate the data options.